# embeded video in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angular app, I have list of embedded video, and I want to show this embedded video in my view. My code is given below:

**Angular arrayList**

```
 .filter('unsafe', function() {
      return function(url) {
          var newUrl =  url.replace(/&lt;/g, "<").replace(/&gt;/g, ">");
          return newUrl ;
      }
 })



controller('', function($scope) { 

    $scope.videoLink = [
      '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cwXfv25xJUw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
      '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cKJvScGB5Ak" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
      '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/W9xtFtOA7_8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
    ];

 });
```

**html view**

```
  <div ng-repeat="url in videoLink">
       <!-- {{url}} --> <!-- only show plain text -->

       <!-- <div ng-html-bind='url'></div> --> <!-- nothing shown --> 

       <!-- {{url | unsafe}} --> <!-- only show plain text -->
  </div>
```

How can I solve this problem???

Answer (score 0):

Rather than the videoLink array containing a collection of HTML elements as strings, could you instead just make that list contain the YouTube embed URLs? It looks like the rest of the iframe elements are exactly the same.

If you did that, then I believe the following would work:

```
<div ng-repeat="url in videoLink">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="{{url | unsafe}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use my responsive youtube directive: https://github.com/Citrullin/angular-responsive-youtube

I used only $scope and $sce for the url.
In your example. You can create a scope variable where you save all your youtube urls. In your view, you can use ng-repeat and inside the directive:

Answer (score 0):

I used filter for this solution please check the below code.

**Html**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller = "mycontroll">
    <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="video in videos track by $index">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe width="420" height="315" ng-src="{{video|trustAsResourceUrl}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div><!-- container end -->
```

**JS**

```
  var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
    app.controller("mycontroll",function($scope){
        $scope.videos=[
            'https://www.youtube.com/embed/Pdaw-ipnPPc',
            'https://www.youtube.com/embed/OssRAVZhsRk',
            'https://www.youtube.com/embed/gf6lhGV6DNs',
            'https://www.youtube.com/embed/Pdaw-ipnPPc',
            'https://www.youtube.com/embed/OssRAVZhsRk',
            'https://www.youtube.com/embed/gf6lhGV6DNs'
        ];
    });
    app.filter('trustAsResourceUrl', ['$sce', function($sce) {
        return function(val) {
            return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(val);
        };
    }])
```